# Nuxt-i18n: how to load messages asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I am building a multilingual Nuxt web app. 
Using this example from the official [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/examples/i18n/) (Codepen [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/i18n?from-embed)), I no longer want to use local JSON files where my translations  are saved to work as defined in the code below:

```
messages: {
      'en': require('~/locales/en.json'), # I want to get this asynchronously from an HTTP URL
      'fr': require('~/locales/fr.json') # I want to get this asynchronously from an HTTP URL
    }
```

I wonder what available alternatives to set asynchronously `en` and `fr` values by reading the JSON data from a URL instead?

**plugins/i18n.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

export default ({ app, store }) => {
  // Set i18n instance on app
  // This way we can use it in middleware and pages asyncData/fetch
  app.i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: store.state.locale,
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    messages: {
      'en': require('~/locales/en.json'), # How to get this asynchronously?
      'fr': require('~/locales/fr.json') # # How to get this asynchronously?
    }
  })

  app.i18n.path = (link) => {
    if (app.i18n.locale === app.i18n.fallbackLocale) {
      return `/${link}`
    }

    return `/${app.i18n.locale}/${link}`
  }
}
```

**What I tried**:

```
messages: {
      'en': axios.get(url).then((res) => {        
         return res.data
        } ),
      'fr': require('~/locales/fr.json')
    }
```

Where `url` points to the `/locals/en.json` file which is hosted on my Github profile.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `axios` with `await` directly in the constructor:

```
export default async ({ app, store }) => {
  app.i18n = new VueI18n({ //construction a new VueI18n
    locale: store.state.i18n.locale,
    fallbackLocale: 'de',
    messages: {
      'de': await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/lang/de.json').then((res) => {
        return res.data
      }),
      'en': await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/lang/en.json').then((res) => {
        return res.data
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've a solution with [localise.biz](https://localise.biz) and cross-fetch

First add `async` to the plugins`plugins / i18n.js` function and add `await` to the remote translation calls :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

import getMessages from './localize';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

export default async ({ app, store }) => {
    app.i18n = new VueI18n({
        locale: store.state.locale,
        fallbackLocale: 'en',
        messages: {
            'en': await getMessages('en'),
            'fr': await getMessages('fr')
        }
    });

    app.i18n.path = (link) => {
         if (app.i18n.locale === app.i18n.fallbackLocale) return `/${link}`;

         return `/${app.i18n.locale}/${link}`;
    }
}
```

And create new function for get remote translation :

```
import fetch from 'cross-fetch';

const LOCALIZE_API_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';
const LOCALIZE_URL = 'https://localise.biz/api/export/locale';
const HEADERS = {
    'Authorization': `Loco ${LOCALIZE_API_KEY}`
};

const getMessages = async (locale) => {
const res = await fetch(`${LOCALIZE_URL}/${locale}.json`, { headers: HEADERS });

if (res.status >= 400) throw new Error("Bad response from server");

    return await res.json();
};

export default getMessages;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what i ended up with:

```js
    async asyncData(context){
       // fetch translation for your source
       var translation = await fetch('/translation')
 
       // get locale of current page
       var locale = context.app.i18n.locale
       // set translation for Server Side Rendering
    context.app.i18n.mergeLocaleMessage(locale, translation)
    // save it for use on client side
       return {translation: translation}
     },
    created(){
        // prevent reverting back to not found after hard-loading page.
        this.$i18n.mergeLocaleMessage(this.$i18n.locale, this.translation)
  }
```